# why two decimals add together there are so many zeros in the result, just curious

Tags: javascript, math

I just run this in the console, and this is the result I get, I am just curious why it happened.

```
6.12+9.3
15.420000000000002
```

Comment: General floating-point arithmetic in most langauges.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)